# Use of function in pandas dataframe with multiprocessing

Tags: python, pandas, python-multiprocessing

I am attempting to speed up calculations on a pandas DataFrame using multiprocessing which goes really well minus the fact that assigning the result of the calculation to the df.ix does not work here like it does in my code without trying multiprocessing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41079603/populate-pandas-dataframe-with-values-derived-from-a-function-row-column-names)

I've added a #sanity check to the code which outputs valid values and would make me think this would work just fine, but the DataFrame doesn't get populated (stays as NaN). Does anyone know why that may be, and more importantly, what changes may be needed to plug the values into the DataFrame in the context of multiprocessing?

Output of sanity check:

```
should be setting df.ix[4][1] to: 23.2506112824
should be setting df.ix[0][0] to: 0.0
should be setting df.ix[7][0] to: 15.9574526264
```

code:

```
import mysql.connector
import numpy as np
from colormath.color_objects import LabColor
from colormath.color_diff import delta_e_cie2000
import pandas as pd
from mysql.connector.pooling import MySQLConnectionPool
from multiprocessing import Pool

pool = Pool()
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='user', password='pass',host='localhost', database='database')
cursor = cnx.cursor()
selectstmt = 'SELECT CIE_Lab, ID FROM `database`.`table`'
cursor.execute(selectstmt)
color = cursor.fetchall()
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = color, index = color)
sides = df.index
headers = df.dtypes.index
shape = df.shape[0]

def delta(cie_Lab1, cie_Lab2):
    cie_Lab1 = cie_Lab1[1:]
    cie_Lab1 = cie_Lab1[:-1]
    cie_Lab2 = cie_Lab2[1:]
    cie_Lab2 = cie_Lab2[:-1]
    CIE_list1 = cie_Lab1.split(",")
    CIE_list2 = cie_Lab2.split(",")
    #print CIE_list1
    CIE_L1 = CIE_list1[0]
    CIE_a1 = CIE_list1[1]
    CIE_b1 = CIE_list1[2]
    CIE_L2 = CIE_list2[0]
    CIE_a2 = CIE_list2[1]
    CIE_b2 = CIE_list2[2]
    color1 = LabColor(lab_l=CIE_L1, lab_a=CIE_a1, lab_b=CIE_b1)
    color2 = LabColor(lab_l=CIE_L2, lab_a=CIE_a2, lab_b=CIE_b2)
    deltae = delta_e_cie2000(color1, color2, Kl=1, Kc=1, Kh=1)
    return deltae


def deltas(nums):
    listoflists = []
    for num in range(nums):
        for mun in range(nums):
            listoflists.append([num,mun])
    return listoflists

def update(inp):
    sides = df.index
    headers = df.dtypes.index
    num = inp[0]
    mun = inp[1]
    res = delta(headers[num][0], sides[mun][0])
    #sanity check
    print "should be setting df.ix["+str(mun)+"]["+str(num)+"] to: "+str(res)
    df.ix[mun][num] = res


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(4)
    pool.map(update, deltas(shape))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print df
```

Dataframe example:

```
([69.62248143012944, -54.15108764844451, 67.92070706614288], 1)  \
([69.62248143012944, -54.15108764844451, 67.920...                                                    NaN                
([58.17848217611454, -52.251714243997995, 56.77...                                                NaN                
([87.02539335188214, -32.15758725885986, 66.450...                                                NaN                
([86.86259502866965, -31.483524711078015, 75.14...                                                NaN                
([85.39154525710671, -31.683349117376856, 71.35...                                                NaN
```

Comment: Do you have an error or something? Can you be more specific about what "doesn't work" ?

Comment: No errors are generated, but the values in the dataframe remain as "NaN", not the values in the output of the sanity check print statement

Comment: Ok, I think the issue is that the df you work with in your update is a copy of the main df. This is caused by the python GIL, which forbid having more than 1 thread running. What you need to do is to apply your update function on a df, return it to the Pool and the concatenate them to get your original df back.

Comment: That sounds like it won't help speed up the process at all. There are 8000 rows in the database so the DataFrame is 8000 x 8000. The calculation is dependent upon the values of both the column and index at a given location, meaning that is 64 million times a dataframe with only one value would be returned to a pool.

Comment: It appears the assignment doesn't work because, as HarryPotfleur posits: in the pandas dataframe the function is acting on is a copy. Perhaps there is a way to write this so there is some persistence. Instead of assigning the result of the calculation to an index in that data frame, should I write to a database like SQLite, then read that into a dataframe?